# df.apply(sorted, axis=1) removes column names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Working through Pandas Cookbook.  Counting the Total Number of Flights Between Cities.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('NumPy: {}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Pandas: {}'.format(pd.__version__))
print('-----')

desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 50
pd.options.display.max_columns = 14
# pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

file = "e:\\packt\\data_analysis_and_exploration_with_pandas\\section07\\data\\flights.csv"
flights = pd.read_csv(file)
print(flights.head(10))
print()

# This returns the total number of rows for each group.
flights_ct = flights.groupby(['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']).size()
print(flights_ct.head(10))
print()

# Get the number of flights between Atlanta and Houston in both directions.
print(flights_ct.loc[[('ATL', 'IAH'), ('IAH', 'ATL')]])
print()

# Sort the origin and destination cities:
# flights_sort = flights.sort_values(by=['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR'], axis=1)
flights_sort = flights[['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
print(flights_sort.head(10))
print()

# Passing just the first row.
print(sorted(flights.loc[0, ['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']]))
print()

# Once each row is independently sorted, the column name are no longer correct.
# We will rename them to something generic, then again find the total number of flights between all cities.
rename_dict = {'ORG_AIR': 'AIR1', 'DEST_AIR': 'AIR2'}
flights_sort = flights_sort.rename(columns=rename_dict)
flights_ct2 = flights_sort.groupby(['AIR1', 'AIR2']).size()
print(flights_ct2.head(10))
print()
```

When I get to this line of code my output differs from the authors:

````
```flights_sort = flights[['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']].apply(sorted, axis=1)```
````

My output does not contain any column names.  As a result, when I get to:

````
```flights_ct2 = flights_sort.groupby(['AIR1', 'AIR2']).size()```
````

it throws a KeyError.  This makes sense, as I am trying to rename columns when no column names exist.

My question is, why are the column names gone?  All other output matches the authors output exactly:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7141.48)
NumPy: 1.16.3
Pandas: 0.24.2
-----
   MONTH  DAY  WEEKDAY AIRLINE ORG_AIR DEST_AIR  SCHED_DEP  DEP_DELAY  AIR_TIME  DIST  SCHED_ARR  ARR_DELAY  DIVERTED  CANCELLED
0      1    1        4      WN     LAX      SLC       1625       58.0      94.0   590       1905       65.0         0          0
1      1    1        4      UA     DEN      IAD        823        7.0     154.0  1452       1333      -13.0         0          0
2      1    1        4      MQ     DFW      VPS       1305       36.0      85.0   641       1453       35.0         0          0
3      1    1        4      AA     DFW      DCA       1555        7.0     126.0  1192       1935       -7.0         0          0
4      1    1        4      WN     LAX      MCI       1720       48.0     166.0  1363       2225       39.0         0          0
5      1    1        4      UA     IAH      SAN       1450        1.0     178.0  1303       1620      -14.0         0          0
6      1    1        4      AA     DFW      MSY       1250       84.0      64.0   447       1410       83.0         0          0
7      1    1        4      F9     SFO      PHX       1020       -7.0      91.0   651       1315       -6.0         0          0
8      1    1        4      AA     ORD      STL       1845       -5.0      44.0   258       1950       -5.0         0          0
9      1    1        4      UA     IAH      SJC        925        3.0     215.0  1608       1136      -14.0         0          0

ORG_AIR  DEST_AIR
ATL      ABE         31
         ABQ         16
         ABY         19
         ACY          6
         AEX         40
         AGS         83
         ALB         33
         ANC          2
         ASE          1
         ATW         10
dtype: int64

ORG_AIR  DEST_AIR
ATL      IAH         121
IAH      ATL         148
dtype: int64

*** No columns names ***  Why?

0    [LAX, SLC]
1    [DEN, IAD]
2    [DFW, VPS]
3    [DCA, DFW]
4    [LAX, MCI]
5    [IAH, SAN]
6    [DFW, MSY]
7    [PHX, SFO]
8    [ORD, STL]
9    [IAH, SJC]
dtype: object
```

The author's output. Note the columns names are present.

[image: Author's output]

Comment: When you apply the sorted function, it gives a series object (not a dataframe) with the same index, but a list of the values from each row in sorted order. In other words, you've completely separated the values from their column headers by sorting each row independently, making the columns no longer apply.

Comment: @G.Anderson, Hmm..  The authors shows the output I copied in for that exact line of code.  I am not doubting your answer, given what I am seeing.  How might I correct the issue.  I tried: flights_sort = flights.sort_values(by=['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR'], axis=1), but this also gives me a KeyError.  Note if I get rid of axis=1 it runs without error, but I do not get the desired result.

Comment: Yikes. This is **not good**. I highly recommend Wes' book [Python for Data Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Data-Analysis-Wrangling-IPython/dp/1449319793).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a list object and obliterates the columns:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df.apply(sorted, axis=1)
Out[12]:
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object

In [13]: type(df.apply(sorted, axis=1).iloc[0])
Out[13]: list
```

It's possible that this wouldn't have been the case in earlier pandas... but it would still be bad code.

You can do this by passing the columns explicitly:

```
In [14]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), df.columns), axis=1)
Out[14]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

A more efficient way to do this is to sort the sort the underlying numpy array:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 1]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  1

In [23]: arr = df[["A", "B"]].values

In [24]: arr.sort(axis=1)

In [25]: df[["A", "B"]] = arr

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
```

As you can see this sorts each *row*.

Comment: Aside: I highly recommend Wes' book [Python for Data Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Data-Analysis-Wrangling-IPython/dp/1449319793).

Comment: But I still have my core issue.  I can't use 'rename_dict' because my first sort obliterates the column names.  How do I correctly sort the dataframe by column so that I can apply the renaming?

Comment: @MarkS Oh, I see what they are trying to do. Use `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), df.columns), axis=1)`

Comment: When I try: flights_sort = flights.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), flights.columns), axis=1), I am getting this:     ```flights_sort = flights.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), flights.columns), axis=1)
TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0')```

Comment: @MarkS just do it on these columns df[['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), df.columns), axis=1)

Comment: Changing to this:  flights_sort = flights[['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), flights.columns), axis=1), yields this: ```ValueError: ('Length of passed values is 2, index implies 14', 'occurred at index 0')```

Comment: @MarkS sort = flights[['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x), ['ORG_AIR', 'DEST_AIR']), axis=1)

Comment: @MarkS this because you are only sorting those two columns, not the entire row.

Comment: I now get the exact output the author gets.  If you're ever near Indianapolis, look me up.  I'm buying. I also accepted your last entry as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

A final note.  I just applied @AndyHayden numpy based solution from above.

```
flights_sort = flights[["ORG_AIR", "DEST_AIR"]].values
flights_sort.sort(axis=1)
flights[["ORG_AIR", "DEST_AIR"]] = flights_sort
```

All I can say is … Wow.  What an enormous performance difference.  I get the exact same
correct answer and I get it as soon as I click the mouse as compared to the pandas lambda solution also provided by @AndyHayden which takes about 20 seconds to perform the sort.  That dataset is 58,000+ rows.  The numpy solution returns the sort instantly.

Comment: `.apply` is slow... `.apply` is slow. Repeat after me: `.apply` is slow. It is meant to be a solution of last resort, and it's essentially a regular old for-loop underneath the hood.